# Json schema when the properties required depend on the value of another property

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have a number of requests types I might be sent.
There's a request-type property that may have values "add", "update", "delete" (for example).

Depending on the request type, I will get different properties

If the request type is "add", then I will get additional propertie "add-red", "add-blue", "foo" for example

If the request type is "update,, then "update-xxx", "update-yyy", "update-xxx"

and if "delete" then "foo", "bar"...

Note that some additional properties could appear for more than one request type (see "foo" in the above example)

So I want to validate differently depending on the value of "request-type".

I tried to to

```
"oneOf": [
  {
  ...
  "properties": { "request-type" : { "enum": ["add"] }
                  "add-red": { ...}
                }
  },
  {
  ...
  "properties": { "request-type" : { "enum": ["update"] }
                  "update-xxx": { ...}
                }
  }
```

In the hope that the validator would match the value of the first when deciding which of the "oneOf" would be selected.

This appears itself to be "valid" (in that the VS Code validator thinks it's a valid schema) but doesn't do what I want - it seems when I write the corresponding JSON it always matches the first, and will only accept "add" as its value).

So how should I do this? I can define the JSON format here, so I can require the use of something I can validate somehow.

It's nearly a duplicate of this: [JSON schema anyOf validation based on one of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629866/json-schema-anyof-validation-based-on-one-of-properties) except I think the answer there requires distinct sets of additional properties for each request type.

EDIT: According to the answer to [validation of json schema having oneOf keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964369/validation-of-json-schema-having-oneof-keyword)
it looks like my approach should work so maybe this is just a limitation of the intellisense in MS VS Code?

EDIT2: And this gives another approach: [writing more complex json schemas that have dependencies upon other keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036366/writing-more-complex-json-schemas-that-have-dependencies-upon-other-keys)

I'll have to experiment some more and maybe end up deleting this!

Comment: Looks like a validator limitation. Try your schema here: http://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-05/markup/json

Comment: Thanks. It would be really convenient to use an editor that uses the schema for intellisense style completion though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe instead of `"request-type" : { "enum": ["add"] }`, just use `{ "request-type" : "add"` and then VS Code intellisense might understand the different options.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - the approach of the question works fine.  Using a validator like http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/, I get the behaviour I expect.

It's just that Visual Studio Code's intellisense can't interpret it in a way that means it can provide useful guidance (and to be fair, it's a difficult problem as it means partially matching all the of the alternatives in the "oneOf" to see which ones might still be valid)